# How to use SharePoint Online my site host location with SharePoint 2013 on-premises?

Tags: sharepoint-online

In a hybrid configuration, we want users to have a single profile (the profile in SharePoint Online).  Configuring a trusted my site host location of https://tenantname-my.sharepoint.com almost works, but there are some issues with this.  How can I get this to work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We created a "*my site redirector*" to solve this problem.

1. Create a web application and blank site collection which will host the *my site redirector*.
2. Create a page with code behind and place it at the root of web application (e.g. httx://o365mysites.onpremserver.com/person.aspx)
3. Code logic into person.aspx to create the appropriate URL for a SharePoint Online my site and redirect the browser to that endpoint.
4. Configure the Trusted My Site Host Locations to direct users within the selected audience to the new site hosting your redirector (e.g. httx://o365mysites.onpremserver.com).
5. Be sure to include exception handling which redirects the user to an informative message if the redirector logic should fail for expected and unexpected reasons.

We created this as a deployable, configurable solution package so that it could be deployed and tested across multiple environments (dev, QA, staging, prod, etc..).

Our SharePoint Online instance authenticates against ADFS.  Therefore for the SharePoint Online url in step #3 above, we created *smart links* to provide an SSO experience for on-prem users navigating to profiles online. The redirector directs the browser to a smart link for the requested SharePoint Online profile page.  See this link for more info re: smart links (http://community.office365.com/en-us/wikis/sso/using-smart-links-or-idp-initiated-authentication-with-office-365.aspx).

Hope that helps.

Comment: This is pretty clever and it seems to me to be a lot of work for something that should work out of the box. Maybe a future release will make your (awesome) solution obsolete :S

Answer (score 2):

The answer posted previously is similar to what I found in a very helpful post here:

[jvasilSP - Using an Office 365 SharePoint Online Hybrid Mysite solution](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jvasil/archive/2013/12/04/using-an-office-365-sharepoint-online-hybrid-mysite-solution.aspx)

I configured a trusted my site host location pointing to the on-premises my site host as described in the post, but I had to change the path slightly:

```
https://my.mydomain.com/_layouts/15/custom.aspx
```

i also had to modify the script somewhat:

```
<script type="text/c#" runat="server">
    void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            string account = Request.QueryString["accountname"];
            string target = Request.QueryString["MySiteRedirect"];
            string spoUrl = "";
            if (account != null)
            {
                // Extract domain and name of user from the account name
                int stop = account.IndexOf("\\");
                string user = account.Substring(stop + 1, account.Length - stop - 1);

                // Construct the SPO URL to redirect to
                string spoUser = String.Format("i:0#.f|membership|{0}@<FederatedUPNSuffix>", user);
                spoUrl = "https://<tenantname>-my.sharepoint.com/Person.aspx?accountname=" + Server.UrlEncode(spoUser);

            }
            else
            {
                spoUrl = "https://<tenantname>-my.sharepoint.com/" + (String.IsNullOrEmpty(target) == false ? "_layouts/15/MySite.aspx?MySiteRedirect=" + target : "");

            }

            // Redirect to profile page in SPO
            Response.Redirect(spoUrl);

        }

        catch
        {
            // Handle error as necessary
            throw;
        }
    }
</script>
```

So far, this seems to be working the way I want it to, but it's not tested. Needs error handling, etc...

The site collection approach described in the previous answer also works.  It's a bit more tricky to get configured though.  My environment uses host-named site collections, and i didn't want to create another web application, so for my quick & dirty testing:

- I created a new empty HNSC at /sites/my
- I used SharePoint Designer to create person.aspx in the root of the new HNSC, and pasted the script from above in the head section
- I added a  entry to the SharePoint web.config to allow server side script

I couldn't get this to work with a VirtualPath of "/sites/my/person.aspx" or even "/sites/my/*", so I had to do this:

```
<PageParserPath VirtualPath="/*" CompilationMode="Always" AllowServerSideScript="true" IncludeSubFolders="true" />
```

- I configured the trusted my site host location to point to the new HNSC

URL:

```
https://intranet.mydomain.com/sites/my
```

Obviously this is unacceptable for a production environment, so this would need to be packaged and deployed in a way that doesn't require enabling server side script for all pages.