# Change the default person field hyperlink

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server

I want to redirect users to our custom social profile that we don't use SharePoint or MySites for. I just need an email address or their account name.

e.g. http://customsite/profile?accountname=john.smith@company.com
or http://customsite/profile?accountname=smithj

Is there a way I can force SharePoint to point at this new url instead of MySites or the _layouts/15/userdisp.aspx page?

Answer (score 0):

Updating the render of SPUserField will not help you on all cases, you have a lot of location which user links are displayed.

To make sure all links would be redirected on your custom social profile, you have few solutions:

1. Make your own SharePoint solution package with a custom redirector

   - [Sample 1](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/85622/how-to-use-sharepoint-online-my-site-host-location-with-sharepoint-2013-on-premi),
   - [Sample 2](http://info.summit7systems.com/blog/redirect-user-profiles-and-my-sites-to-sharepoint-online),
   - the userdisp.aspx contains a delegatecontrol "ProfileRedirection" you can build you own routine by a custom user control
2. Not recommended: Add IIS url rewrite rules on each front-end(s) which catch the userdisp.aspx pattern.